# Font Awesome icons don't appear in DOM

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome

When I send a string of icon using props some icons don't appear. 
[image: console warning]

On my DB I have these icons like string STRING type 
[image: DB with icon strings]
Icons like graduation-cap or eye appear normally on page but other icons do not.

```
const CourseIcon = ({
courseType: { type, prefix, custom, faIcon, icon },
className,

...rest
}) => {
return custom ? (
 <img
   src={require(`../../img/course-icons/${icon}.png`)}
   className={classnames('course-icon', className)}
   title={type}
   alt={type}
 />
) : (
 <FontAwesomeIcon
   className={classnames('course-icon', className)}
   title={type}
   icon={faIcon}
   {...rest}
 />
);
};

CourseIcon.propTypes = {
courseType: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default CourseIcon;
```

Here is the code. When I use console.log on courseType all is defined.

Answer (score 1):

The new font-awesome is split the icon styles into several packages. After you installed the ones you need and imported the icons from them into the project properly you have to define the style source as well when use the icon with `FontAwesomeIcon`.

For example:

import and library definition:

```
// Notice that this icon comes from the regular style package.
import { faKeyboard } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons';
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';

library.add(faKeyboard);
```

Then, inside your component:

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';

// ... other code parts

const YourComponent = () => {
  return (
    // The first element of the icon array will define your icon style
    // far = font awesome regular (obviously)
    // The rest of it will define the icon itself
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={['far', 'keyboard']} />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

an example for image export default component

```
import from const similar example
 const render_example =  
({
courseType: { type, prefix, custom, faIcon, icon },
className,

...rest
}) => and concat your render with this const if is neccesary

import React from 'react';
import './styles/styles.css';
import Logo from '../images/logo.svg';

class ClassName extends React.Component {
render() {
  return (
    <div className="class">
     <div className="_header">
      <img src={Logo} alt="Logo de la conferencia" />
       </div>
        <div className="section-name__class">
         <Gravatar className="image_avatar" email={this.props.email} />
          <h1>
          {this.props.firstname} <br /> {this.props.only__name}
          </h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default image;
```

Comment: Thanks guys. I fixed it problem was in library and in DB prefixes. I used part of your advices